# Add HTML elements programmatically

Tags: development, visual-studio, sharepoint-server, html, aspx

I think it is a very simple question, but I'm just stuck on it.

I'm developing custom page for my SharePoint 2010 portal, and I need to add a button (or other elements) to my .aspx page:

```
<input type="button" id="btnID" onclick="window.location.href='/CustomPage.aspx'" value="GO!" />
```

I've tried to do it from codebehind:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button button = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button();
button.OnClientClick = "window.location.href='/CustomPage.aspx'";
button.ID = "btnID";
button.Text = "GO!";
IVersionedContent9.Controls.Add(button);
```

However, I get this on the page:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$UIVersionedContent9$btnID" value="GO!" onclick="window.location.href='/CustomPage.aspx';WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$UIVersionedContent9$btnID&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UIVersionedContent9_btnID" />
```

I'm not sure with the class, but maybe something else is wrong...

How can I add simple HTML (not ASP.NET) button to the page, without any additional values?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do **Response.Write**, or you can use **asp:Literal**.

```
var ltlCnt = new LiteralControl();
string divStart = @"<div>";
ltlCnt.Text += divStart;
string divEnd = @"</div>";
ltlCnt.Text += divEnd;

this.[divOnPage].Controls.Add(ltlCnt);
```

Comment: pls vote the answer if that helped you :)